# What is the proper syntax for shimming a method with optional parameters using Pose?

Tags: c#, pose

I'm trying to use https://github.com/tonerdo/pose. I have a method in another assembly that looks like this (VB.NET):

```vb
    Public Class Item Parent
        Public Function GetItems(
            ByVal Optional a As Integer = 0,
            ByVal Optional b As Integer = 0,
            ByVal Optional c As Integer = 0,
            ByVal Optional d As Integer = 0) As List(Of Item)
    ...
```

I'm trying to figure out how to shim this. This give me the error `An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments`.

```cs
    var mockItems = new List<Item>();
    Shim.Replace(() => Is.A<ItemParent>().GetItems())
        .With(delegate (ItemParent@this) { return mockItems; });
```

This give me `Pose.Exceptions.InvalidShimSignatureException: Mismatched instance types`

```cs
    var mockItems = new List<Item>();
    Shim.Replace(() => Is.A<ItemParent>().GetItems(Is.A<int>(), Is.A<int>(), Is.A<int>(), Is.A<int>()))
        .With(delegate () { return mockItems; });
```

And these variations give me `Pose.Exceptions.InvalidShimSignatureException: Parameters count do not match`

```cs
    var mockItems = new List<Item>();
    Shim.Replace(() => Is.A<ItemParent>().GetItems(Is.A<int>(), Is.A<int>(), Is.A<int>(), Is.A<int>()))
        .With(delegate (ItemParent@this) { return mockItems; });

    var mockItems = new List<Item>();
    Shim.Replace(() => Is.A<ItemParent>().GetItems(Is.A<int>(), Is.A<int>(), Is.A<int>(), Is.A<int>()))
        .With(delegate (ItemParent@this, int a, int b, int c, int d) { return mockItems; });
```

What is the proper syntax?

Comment: Ever got this working?

Comment: @404, I've moved on to a different job so I haven't needed to, but I do see that the author of the project is hoping to revive the project, so there maybe there's hope: https://github.com/tonerdo/pose/issues/63